# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@apollo/client/core'

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-angular

I am using the apollo-angular library in my angular 15 project. It works very well on my local, but when I push to my CI it fails with the below error:

````
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@apollo/client/core' in '/home/runner/work/my-frontend/my-frontend/node_modules/apollo-angular/fesm2022'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@apollo/client/core' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
resolve '@apollo/client/core' in '/home/runner/work/my-frontend/my-frontend/node_modules/apollo-angular/fesm2022' ```
````

Comment: do you CI run `npm i` or `npm ci` when you change `package.json`

Comment: Every new package I add always runs smoothly in the CI. except for this

Comment: What about your CI configurations? Maybe it has some custom restrictions. Also what about the full logs. Is this the only error? The cause might be described in previouse steps.

Comment: I think I have been able to narrow it down to Webpack. it fails with the command 
```npx webpack --config config/webpack.renderer.js --mode development --progress --profile```

Comment: so at first try the existing answer, it might work, if not then check what's going on in `webpack.renderer.js` and also check webpack version compatibility in you package dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In some very specific bundling environments, you might need to specify `@apollo/client/core/index.js` instead of `@apollo/client/core`.

As it seems that this is a change that needs to be done in `apollo-angular`, maybe leave a comment over in https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/issues/2172 ?

Comment: Similar to the issue I have. I found a fix  
`
test: /\.m?js/,
          resolve: {
             fullySpecified: false
          }
` 
but this takes forever to run as the nodemodule is not excluded, since the issue is in the module.

Comment: Another thing that I noticed that relates to the solution you shared, is that if I navigate to my nodemodule and append .index.js. to the import, then it works. but again it doesn't make sense for me to change my nodemodules. or have no idea on how to programmatically do that

Comment: @valentine Please add a comment to above GitHub issue and describe what is causing this problem for you, so the problem can be addressed by the package authors. They won't fix it if you don't tell them.